# When dealing with finite groups, if $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$ and if $ba=a^4b^3$, how do I prove that ${\rm ord}(a^4b)={\rm ord}(a^2b^3)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

When dealing with finite groups, if $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$ and if $ba=a^4b^3$, how do I prove that ${\rm ord}(a^4b)={\rm ord}(a^2b^3)$?

I know that ${\rm ord}(ab)={\rm ord}(ba)$, and ${\rm ord}(a)={\rm ord}(a^{-1})$.

I think the answer might have something to do with conjugates in groups - perhaps showing that $a^4b$ and $a^2b^3$ are conjugates so that they may have the same order?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, $a^4b$ and $a^2b^3$ may not be conjugates. However they both look similar to $a^4b^3$.

We may write:

$$a^4b = a^4b^3b^{-2} = bab^{-2}, \ a^2b^3 = a^{-2}a^4b^3 = a^{-2}ba$$

Now we may derive the result using $\operatorname{ord}(ab) = \operatorname{ord}(ba)$ and $\operatorname{ord}(a) = \operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes more sense now.